# How to apply fuzzy membership function to binary images?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, image-processing, fuzzy

I'm implementing this paper "[Neural Network-Based Edge Detection for Automated 
Medical Diagnosis by Lu et al](https://digitalcommons.calpoly.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?referer=https://www.google.com/&httpsredir=1&article=1242&context=eeng_fac)" and it says it uses a fuzzy membership function to improve its generalization accuracy.

It uses the following function:

[image]

[image]

So using this function the authors are able to change their images as follows:

[image]

I've tried recreating this data but unfortunately, I'm too much of a noob when it comes to fuzzy maths(never implemented something using fuzzy logic). I tried creating this by passing images through a numpy function as follows:

```py
def fuzzy_membership(images, e):
    return np.exp(-((images - e)**2/ (2*(0.25**2))))
```

Using this if I input an image I get the following:

```
          (Fuzzy function with e=1)
| 0 0 1 |                                | 3.3456e-04  3.3456e-04  1 |
| 0 0 1 |------------------------------> | 3.3456e-04  3.3456e-04  1 |
| 0 0 1 |                                | 3.3456e-04  3.3456e-04  1 |
(IMAGE)                                        (Resultant image)


and similarly with e=0

          (Fuzzy function with e=0)
| 0 0 1 |                                | 1 1  3.3456e-04 |
| 0 0 1 |------------------------------> | 1 1  3.3456e-04 |
| 0 0 1 |                                | 1 1  3.3456e-04 |
(IMAGE)                                        (Resultant image)
```

Training dataset formed in this manner generalizes horribly and it's obvious why. Values never go as low as 3.3456x10^-4 in normalized grayscale images(grayscale images dived by 255).

So, how do I go about implementing the fuzzy membership function correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Applying this function to binary values does not make much sense, since it will lead to the results shown by you, i.e. only ones and very small floating-point values. Notice that the authors say, that they used grayscale images, so let's apply this function to grayscale image.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def transform(x):
    return np.exp(-((x-1)**2)/(2*0.25**2))

plt.figure(figsize=(20,10))
plt.gray()
plt.subplot(121)
plt.imshow(lena/256)
plt.subplot(122)
plt.imshow(transform(lena/256))
plt.show()
```

[image]

As you can see, it made the values more extreme: small values were turned to smaller ones, while large values were turned to larger ones, in an exponentially-squared way. Simple as that.

Having this said, I can't see how is this anyhow related to "fuzzy logic", and the authors don't explain what do they mean by "fuzzy concepts" that they mention in the paper.

Comment: Thanks a bunch for the reply. The authors do state that they use the fuzzy concepts during the training process on the training data they have, which are 3x3 binary images of the patterns they want their neural net to learn. So any idea how I can make the neural net learn these patterns of a relative sharp shift of intensity?

Comment: (Adding to my previous comment) without me creating by hand a data set with a relatively sharp shift in intensities

Comment: @RafayKhan from their description I don't feel that I understand their methodology in details, they provided very vague description. As far as understand, the key point in here is that they trained the NN on hand-made dataset of edges, plus the "fuzzy" preprocessing.